# I'm facing an issue with OnehotEncoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


dataset = pd.read_csv('googleplaystore.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, :3].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder


labelencoder = LabelEncoder()


X[:, 1] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 1])


onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])


X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'iHoroscope - 2018
>   Daily Horoscope & Astrology'

Here's the link to csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z3uT_tU9QsdE8QSBd8husItHeh36ztZa/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Maybe you could post a few rows of the data file, since it's only 3 columns. It might help to see both before and after the label encoder step.
(I can't access google drive from work)

Comment: You are doing `onehotencoder.fit_transform(X)` Your `X` will have some string values causing this error. Are you sure it is not a typo to use `X` but not `X[:, 1]`.?

Comment: Here's what I get if I try onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 1]): ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:        array=[ 1.  1.  1. ... 21.  4. 19.].                        Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: You can use `pd.get_dummies(dataset['col'])` or `pd.get_dummies(dataset.iloc[ : , : 3)` to get the same result as the `OneHotEncoder` from sklearn

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DictVectorizer as per the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33010943/10548514. As for directly dealing with  problem involving the OneHotEncoder:

When running your code, it isn't using the correct column for one-hot encoding, (`categorical_features` is deprecated), so after your label encoding, a quick and dirty fix is to apply the transformation specifically to the column you want (reshaping is necessary):

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
y = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1))
```

Comment: Does 'X[:, 1] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 1])' in the code not do that job?

Comment: `onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder();
y = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1))` worked for me.

Comment: Also, you  should consider removing the nans from dataset after you read your .csv file

Answer (score 0):

Since `categorical_features` is deprecated since version 0.20 (and will be removed in 0.22) `scikit-learn` suggests you use [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) instead.

It is just a convenient way of applying different transformers  to different columns.

So here's how you can one-hot encode your column using `ColumnTransformer`:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

#Specify what you want to do, and provide column index
ct = ColumnTransformer([('ohe', OneHotEncoder(), [1])])

ohe_category = ct.fit_transform(X)
```

This gives you a one-hot encoded sparse matrix. You can convert it to `dense`:

```
ohe_category.todense()
```

That said, I would suggest you go ahead with [pd.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) (as @JonasCristens has mentioned) since it's much simpler to use:

```
pd.get_dummies(dataset['Category'])
```